# Change sling.home in Azure App Service container

Tags: aem, sling

I'm running the "apache/sling" Docker image in an Azure App Service. AFAICT, App Service only supports visibility/persistence in the "/home" directory in the container. Therefore, I think I need to change Sling's "sling.home" property from its default "/opt/sling" to something like "/home/sling".

I suspect I have to create my own Docker image based on "apache/sling", but still, between all the possible ways to set "sling.home", in OSGi framework properties, JAR files, command line arguments, etc., I'm lost to figure out what to actually change in my own Docker image. Should I build some part of this from modified source? Or what?

BTW, this is all in order to start working with Sling until my org eventually gets AEM.

Comment: While is true that AEM relies on Sling, are you org planning to use AEM in the short term? Since AEM is more than just Apache Sling and I am not sure how much of this work can be reused when you move to AEM.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure either. But my org is taking a _very_ long time to acquire AEM, and I'm worried about being able to migrate our large existing site to AEM by a desired date if I don't get a head start.